Cannot connect to MySQL-Server with DataGrip
The MySQL-Server is running in a docker container, configured with docker-compose:
services:
  legacy_db:
    image: liupeng0518/mysql:5.7-arm64
    environment:
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: symfony
      MYSQL_USER: symfony
      MYSQL_PASSWORD: symfony
      MYSQL_DATABASE: symfony
    command:
      - '--default-authentication-plugin=mysql_native_password'
      - '--sql_mode='
      - '--max_allowed_packet=1073741824'
    volumes:
      - legacy_db:/var/lib/mysql
    healthcheck:
      test: ["CMD", "mysqladmin", "-u", "root", "-psymfony", "ping", "-h", "localhost"]
      timeout: 5s
      retries: 30
      interval: 1s
    ports:
      - '3307:3306'

Error in DataGrip Build #DB-241.17890.24:
The server has terminated the handshake. The protocol list option (`enabledTLSProtocols`) is set, this option might cause connection issues with some versions of MySQL. Consider removing the protocol list option in the JDBC driver.

What must be done to connect to the database?

Not sure about datagrip, but the issue with : enabledTLSProtocols is causing a problem.  TLS is a form of encryption/security, and 1.2 is the new standard, particularlly with sending emails that are secure.  I don't see an option for that on your config, so it must be a default value that you didn't include to change?  It might be required for datagrip is my guess, but I have no idea personally.

IMHO it's a datagrip problem, not a MySQL/Docker thing...

I believe that is the case as well, I don't see it listed as an option in your file, so it seems like maybe datagrip requires it so you can try updating your config to include that feature since it seems it is set according to the error.

As mentioned, you need to check the TLS protocols supported by your container. By the way, did you try changing the JDBC driver version? Nonetheless, changing the useSSL value on the Data Sources tab > Advanced to false can probably help as a workaround.

In DataGrip open "Advanced" tab in your connection, find "useSSL" and set "False" value. It works for me.
